# Omnisharp and DotNET Core Debugger on Windows 10 32-Bit

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I just installed Visual Studio Code and the DotNET Core SDK on a fresh Windows 10 32-Bit machine. However, I don't get it to run and to work properly.

I've loaded the csharp extension (Omnisharp) in Visual Studio Code. It is obvious that it seems to load x64 packages instead of x86:

```
[INFO] Starting OmniSharp at 'd:\Entwicklung\MyFirstApp'...
[INFO] Installing to C:\Users\Daniel\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.1.5\.omnisharp
[INFO] Attempting to download omnisharp-1.9-beta5-win-x64-net451.zip...
[INFO] Downloading to C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-1252lY4HMeX6qNhB.tmp...
```

This leads to the error that the Debugger cannot be installed:

```
Error: Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETStandardApp,Version=v1.5' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x86, win81-x86, win8-x86, win7-x86'. Possible causes:
1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run `dotnet restore`
2. The project does not list one of 'win10-x86, win81-x86, win8-x86, win7-x86' in the 'runtimes' section.
Error: 

System.InvalidOperationException: Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETStandardApp,Version=v1.5' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x86, win81-x86, win8-x86, win7-x86'. Possible causes:
1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run `dotnet restore`
2. The project does not list one of 'win10-x86, win81-x86, win8-x86, win7-x86' in the 'runtimes' section.
at....
```

How to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Same here on Windows 7 32bit. I have even tried to Google the version of Omnisharp for a downloadable package but, to be honest, I wouldn't know what to do with it if I found one.

Answer (score 1):

I have a netbook that I was hoping to use with Windows 7 32 bit and VSCode / Omnisharp and I have hit that wall as well.

[Omnisharp only supports 64 bit at the moment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp). There is no known plan for a 32 bit version.

What is confusing is that it USED to be 32 bit compatible! Either make the switch to 64 bit (if your hardware allows it) or set up a different tool chain (perhaps using SharpDevelop?).

People have already requested this change but the devs [don't seem to take it seriously](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/338).